# New ArrayList() on Child Object does not update reference in parent object

Tags: java

I thought that everything was based on references in Java. I have a complex object that contains a child List.

```
ParentObj
|-- ...
|-- List<String> childList
```

when I modify the childList directly, I see that "ParentObj" updates its childList reference accordingly.

```
childList.add("Hello");
```

But when I do

```
if (childList == null) {
  childList = new ArrayList<String>();
}
```

I see that "ParentObj" **still has a NULL child List**! Something is different about this case, I was expecting the ParentObj reference to get updated as it does for setting/adding.

Comment: Can you provide an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for this?

Comment: There is very definitely something not showing in your question. If `childList` really were `null`, then calling `childList.add`, you would get a `NullPointerException`. Please provide more context.

Answer (score -2):

Java passes references by value. Meaning there's a duplicate of the reference that's passed as method argument. So when you assign `childList` and if it's not original reference then assignment was done to the duplicate reference.

That's why you should be using `setter` method.